# Firebird C# padrão singleton

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, firebird, singleton

Estou utilizando a seguinte função para conectar ao banco de dados, estou programando em C# no Visual Studio 2013.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Conexao
    {

        private static String strConn = Properties.Settings.Default.caminhoFbConnection;
        private static FbConnection conn = null;


        public static void Conection()
        {

        }

        public static FbConnection getConnection()
        {
            try
            {

                if (conn == null)
                {
                    conn = new FbConnection(strConn);
                    conn.Open();
                    return conn;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        return conn;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        return conn;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception excep)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro - " + excep.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static void closeConnection()
        {
            try
            {

                conn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception excep)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excep.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Minha ideia de como utilizar esta função seria, o conexão somente abrir, realizar as operações necessárias e em seguida fechar a conexão. Porém estou com alguns problemas.

Ao utilizar este modelo de conexão o *pool* de conexão do Firebird vai ficar somente com 1 conexão ativa, ou quando eu abrir a conexão e fechá-la o *pool* vai aumentando?

Criei no Firebird uma tabela de exemplo com auto incremento da chave primária usando *trigger*, porém está incrementando de 2 em 2, quando eu abro e fecho a conexão, se eu inserir dois itens sem fechar a conexão ele incrementa de 1 em 1. O que pode esta ocasionando isto?

Comment: Só por curiosidade. Por que não usa um ORM?

Comment: O pool de conexões não é do Firebird mas sim do ADO.NET. No mais, não consegui entender  o problema. Experimente revisar a pontuação na sua pergunta e experimente informar também o código consumidor desta classe. Por fim, o que você está fazendo parece demasiado e desnecessariamente complexo. Que tal fazer apenas um método que entregue sempre um novo objeto de conexão e deixar com o código consumidor a responsabilidade de descartar a conexão (o que é muito simples usando o bloco *using*)?

Answer (score 2):

@wmaicon951, não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta, mas a respeito de se manter várias conexões ativas com o banco de dados creio que isto resolver. Onde tenho os métodos de `abrirConexao`, `fecharConexao` e `executarComando`, sendo que sempre que eu precisar chamar o método `executarComando` estarei garantindo que a conexão com o banco sempre será fechada após a realização do comando com o bloco:

```
 finally
  {
    fecharConexao(cn);
  }
```

Segue o código que tenho:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
using Demo_NFe.Code.BLL;

namespace MeuProjeto.Code.DAL
{
    class ConexaoBDDAL
    {
        public FbConnection abrirConexao()
        {
            #region Método responsável por abrir a conexão com Banco de Dados

            FbConnection conexao = null;

            UtilitariosBLL util = new UtilitariosBLL();

            try
            {
                string strConexao = String.Empty;
                string banco = "nome_banco"
                string servidor = "localhost";
                string usuario = "SYSDBA";
                string senha = "masterkey";

                strConexao = @"User=" + usuario + "; "
                + @"Password=" + senha + "; "
                + @"Database=" + banco + "; "
                + @"DataSource=" + servidor + "; "
                + "Dialect=3; "
                + "Charset=WIN1252; "
                + "Role=; "
                + "Connectionlifetime =15; "
                + "Pooling =true; "
                + "MinPoolSize =0; "
                + "MaxPoolSize =50; "
                + "PacketSize =8192; "
                + "ServerType =0";

                conexao = new FbConnection(strConexao);

                if (conexao.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    conexao.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro ao Estabelecer a Comunicação com o Banco de Dados, por favor verrifique se todas as configurações "
                               + "foram informadas corretamente!", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);             
            }

            return conexao;

            #endregion
        }


        //Método para Fechar a Conexão com o Banco de Dados
        public void fecharConexao(FbConnection cn)
        {
            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                cn.Close();
        }

        //Método para Exerculta comandos SQL
        public void executarComando(string strQuery)
        {
            FbConnection cn = new FbConnection();

            try
            {
                cn = abrirConexao();
                FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = strQuery.ToString();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro ao Excultar o Comando SQL, Por Favor Certifique-se se o mesmo foi escrito corretamente!", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            finally
            {
                fecharConexao(cn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```